# Invoking VBA Shell function but nothing happens

Tags: vba, shell, excel

I've wrote my first macro and want to run an JAR-file from it:

```
Sub verarbeitungTest()

    Dim pfad As String
    pfad = "C:\temp\StapelverarbeitungOutput.xml"

    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    fileExists = (Dir(pfad) <> "")

    If fileExists Then
      Kill pfad
    End If

    Dim test As XlXmlExportResult

    test = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("edts_Zuordnung").Export(URL:=pfad)

    If test = xlXmlExportValidationFailed Then

        MsgBox ("Validation error!")
        Kill pfad

    Else

        MsgBox ("Good!")
        Dim procID As Integer
        procID = Shell("java -jar H:\Sources\workspace_eclipse_luna\JImp\target\JImp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar H:\Sources\workspace_eclipse_luna\JImp\config\log4j_config.xml H:\Sources\workspace_eclipse_luna\JImp\config\JImpConfig.xml C:\temp\StapelverarbeitungOutput.xml")

    End If

End Sub
```

If I run the macro the message box is shown but after that nothing happens (my JAR-file shows also a dialog). If I copy the command ("java -jar ....") in cmd it works fine.. All the paths are correct!

Maybe you can help me!
Thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the path of the JAVA installation location.. Something like.

```
Shell """C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java"" -jar H:\Sources\workspace_eclipse_luna\JImp\target\JImp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!! My java dialog (MessageDialog from package org.eclipse.jface.dialogs) is not displayed properly.. Any ideas?

Comment: adding "VbAppWinStyle.vbNormalFocus" as second parameter solved my problem!

Comment: Glad to hear you have the issue solved ! Good luck ! :)